# Conditional styling doesnt seems to be working?

Tags: react-native

I've created a `TextInput` that expects to change fontColor based on length

```js
handleInput = text => {
  this.setState({ input: text });
}
...
<TextInput
  style={{ color: this.state.input.length > 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}
  onChangeText={this.handleInput}
/>
```

My understanding is on every `state` change there will be a re-render happening and hence it should be able to re-evaluate the expression and show `green` color, however that's not the case, the font will only be showing `red` color.

I've created a snack as reproducable issue: https://snack.expo.io/ryXHyeWJH

Comment: it seems that `TextInput` doesn't re-apply the styling. even if you do `const color = this.state.input.length > 0 ? 'green' : 'red';
    console.log(color)` the styling doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the classname package. Install with npm install classnames --save. It makes conditional styling easy. Use something like this`className={classNames({ this.state.input.length > 0 ? 'color-green' : 'color-red' })}`. Note ou have to create those css classes.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found out that such issue only happen to those uncontrolled TextInput component.

```js
<TextInput
  style={{ color: this.state.input.length > 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}
  onChangeText={this.handleInput}
/>
```

If it's controlled component then the style will be applied correctly as below

```js
<TextInput
  style={{ color: this.state.input.length > 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}
  value={this.state.input}
  onChangeText={this.handleInput}
/>
```